# Cannot reinitialise DataTable, How to Update datatable after submit without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable

I have windows ready ajax datatable but I want to update datatable after adding submit.

Here's my code

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    const selectValueBatch = document.getElementById('valueBatch').value;
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "/DIYRate/onLoadCriteria",
        data: { batchID: selectValueBatch },
        success: function (result) {
            var js = result.criTbls;
            var table = $('#crteriaTbl').DataTable({
                "data": js,
                "aLengthMenu": [
                [10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
                [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]
                ],
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "columns": [
                       { "data": "criteriaID" },
                       { "data": "batchID" },
                       { "data": "criteria" },
                       { "data": "description" },
                       { "data": "percentage" },
                       }
                ]
            });
     })
```

This is what i tried, This is what i see to other post but not working.

```
   document.getElementById('btnCreateCrit').addEventListener('click', function () {

        const batchID = document.getElementById('batchID').value;
        const criteria = document.getElementById('criteriaName').value;
        const descript = document.getElementById('descript').value;
        const percent = document.getElementById('percent').value;


        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/DIYRate/criteriaCreate',
            data: { batchID: batchID, criteria: criteria, descript: descript, percent: percent },
            success: function (result) {
                result.stats == 0 ? toastr.error(result.message) : toastr.success(result.message);
                 $('#crteriaTbl').DataTable.ajax.reload();
            }       
        })
```

Comment: `#btnCreateCrit` is a typeless button in a form, or a submit button? `form` is a link, and submitting a form navigates to a new location (or to the current location, if action attribute of the form is not defined). To stay on the current page, you've to prevent the form submission.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not put form action since I use ajax to submit the inputs value into my controller. I'm trying to find to refresh datatable automatically after ajax success not the whole page.

Comment: Like said above, if there's no `action` attribute, the current page is reloaded. Add `event` argument to the argument list of your event handler function, and as a first line do [`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you have to create a function for example `loaddata`.
then put your code that and it loads datatable in function. after that call the function in `window.load` and also call function in submit success. it will work!